# Converting jupyter cells to png

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hello I am trying to convert the cells of a jupyter notebook into pngs. I have however ran into a bump where I am trying to size the images in a reasonable way.

Here is how it currently works:
I got the file:
convert.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html2image import Html2Image
import sys

html = sys.stdin.read()
soupHandler = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
cells = soupHandler.findAll("div", id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('cell-id='))
notebook = soupHandler.findAll("body", {"class": "jp-Notebook"})[0]

hti = Html2Image()

for cell in cells:
    div_id = cell["id"]
    notebook.clear()
    notebook.append(cell)
    hti.screenshot(soupHandler.__str__(), save_as=f"{div_id}.png")
```

which I then run using the following command(I am using Windows 10):

> python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --stdout --to html .\mynotebook.ipynb | python3 convert.py

As stated previously; the problem is sizing the images in a reasonable way where I am not hardcoding in pixel sizes.

I am also open to other less rag-tag solutions to the problem of converting jupyer cells to individual images if there are any.